# Can't get the $_POST Variable

Tags: php, html, multi-upload

**It should be a multiple upload form for pictures**

I get the HTML Code for a Upload-Form:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" id="uploadform" name="uploadform" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
        <label id="filelabel" for="fileselect">Choose the Pictures</label>
        <input type="file" id="fileselect" class="fileuplaod" name="uploads[]" multiple />
        <span class="text">Exist Album</span><br />
        <select id="existAlbum" name="existAlbum" size="1">
            <option value="noAlbum">SELECT ALBUM</option>       
        </select>
        <span class="text">OR</span>
        <span class="text">New Album</span><br />
        <input id="newAlbum" name="newAlbum" type="text" maxlength="20" placeholder="ALBUM NAME"/>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

The form link to the uploaded.php. But there i get:

```
Notice: Undefined index: existAlbum in E:\xampp\htdocs\fotokurs\upload\upload.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined index: newAlbum in E:\xampp\htdocs\fotokurs\upload\upload.php on line 12
```

Here's the upload.php:

```
<?PHP  
$allowedExtensions = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'); 

$maxSize = 20971520;  

$i = 0;  

$first = 0;

$exist_album = $_POST['existAlbum']; 
$new_album = $_POST['newAlbum'];
```

Where is my fault? I can't find it...

**EDIT**
Add following to my code:

```
if( isset( $_POST['existAlbum'] ) or isset( $_POST['newAlbum'] ) ){
    $exist_album = $_POST['existAlbum']; 
    $new_album = $_POST['newAlbum'];
}else{
    echo 'no album <br />';
}
print_r($_POST);
```

new output:

```
no album 
Array ( ) 
Notice: Undefined variable: new_album in E:\xampp\htdocs\fotokurs\upload\upload.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined variable: exist_album in E:\xampp\htdocs\fotokurs\upload\upload.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined variable: new_album in E:\xampp\htdocs\fotokurs\upload\upload.php on line 22

Notice: Undefined variable: exist_album in E:\xampp\htdocs\fotokurs\upload\upload.php on line 23
```

Comment: What do you see in `print_r($_POST)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your issues is that `existAlbum` has no actual values associated with it.

You have `<option>Select Album</option>` which has no value associated with the option element.  If there is no value associated, the select element is not posted to the server.  You should change it to be:

`<option value="">Select Album</option>`

**EDIT**

Since the user only has to supply one or the other, you should use the following to set your variables:

```
$existsAlbum = (isset($_POST['existAlbum']) && !empty($_POST['existAlbum'])) ? $_POST['existAlbum'] : 'defaultValue';
$newAlbum = (isset($_POST['newAlbum']) && !empty($_POST['newAlbum'])) ? $_POST['newAlbum'] : 'defaultValue';
```

One important thing to note is that [Internet Explorer does not support the placeholder attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_placeholder.asp).

**EDIT 2**

Here is my quick test page that worked test.php:

```
  <form action="upload.php" method="post" id="uploadform" name="uploadform" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
    <label id="filelabel" for="fileselect">Choose the Pictures</label>
    <input type="file" id="fileselect" class="fileuplaod" name="uploads[]" multiple />
    <span class="text">Exist Album</span><br />
    <select id="existAlbum" name="existAlbum" size="1">
      <option value="noAlbum">SELECT ALBUM</option>       
    </select>
    <span class="text">OR</span>
    <span class="text">New Album</span><br />
    <input id="newAlbum" name="newAlbum" type="text" maxlength="20" placeholder="ALBUM NAME"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

upload.php

```
    <pre>
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
<?php print_r($_FILES); ?>
    </pre>
```

results

```
Array
(
    [existAlbum] => noAlbum
    [newAlbum] => 
)
Array
(
    [uploads] => Array
        (
            //Contents here
        )
)
```

Comment: And yes, i don't use IE. For IE, i want to fix it later. But it should work in webkit browsers...

Comment: @dTDesign You didn't add any values to your `existAlbum` like I suggested.  Even if you don't want them to use the option `Select Album`, you should give it a value of `value=""`.  Take a look at my edit on how you should set your variables.

Comment: @dTDesign Are the contents of $_POST still empty or is at least one of the variables set?

Comment: @dTDesign I just posted the example I am using to test with, and am getting values (just a copy and paste of your code).  Do you have any Javascript event that runs before the form is submitted?  If so, would you please post that?

Comment: Did you just upload 1 image? Because 1 image works. But i want a multiple upload script. When i use more than 1 image, there are the errors

Comment: @dTDesign I didn't upload anything.  I just clicked the submit button.  I just uploaded 2 png files, and it worked as well.  Nothing will show up in `$_POST['uploads']` because that will show up in `$_FILES['upload']`

Comment: +1 for your help! Thank you. But It doesn't work... Now i just insert the scripts step by step and try to find out where the error is...

Comment: @dTDesign You are welcome.  I am sorry that it still isn't working for you.  I hope you figure it out.  If you think of anything else that might help solve your problem, update your question.

Answer (score 0):

If select is not picked you will not get it at all (you expect it to be empty, which is not true). You have to check first

```
$exist_album = isset($_POST['existAlbum']) ? $_POST['existAlbum'] : '<DEFAULT VALUE>';
```

and same for checkbox.

The `newAlbum` thing should work as text inputs are always there. See

```
print_r($_POST);
```

to see what's really in there, and in my case it is - on "empty" submit I get:

```
Array
(
    [existAlbum] => SELECT ALBUM
    [newAlbum] => 
)
```

BTW: you should use `<?php` rather than `<?PHP`.

Comment: you've put ; instead of a : :)

Comment: Take a look to my edit. Thank you. And: is there a difference between php & PHP?

Comment: As for edit - show **full** code, because you got errors **after** `print_r()` so it means you still use this incorrectly in the code

Comment: Yes, because it goes to the else loop and the both variables aren't set. So my script, which use this two variables, paste a error.

Comment: You code is wrong. You should use && (AND) instead of || (OR) because using OR makes no sense as the condition is met when at least one filed is there, but you are still reading both

Answer (score 0):

Try if the value existAlbum get set, because it won't return any value if you there is nothing picked. You could give the existAlbum picker a default='1' or something:

```
 if isset($_POST['existAlbum']){
        echo 'yes';
 }
 else{
      echo 'no';
 }
```

I think that there is something wrong with the rule enctype="multipart/form-data". Try to just remove this, it should be set automatically by your browser.

Comment: I need the enctype for a multiple upload. But also without that, it doesn't work... Take a look to my edit. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have no value for the option select album, even if you don't intend that option to be used give it a value such as 0 so that it will always be set in the POST variables.

```
<option value="0">SELECT ALBUM</option>
<option value="some album">Some Album</option>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

print $_POST Array using `print_r($_POST);` Make sure your form action is correct

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" id="uploadform" name="uploadform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```