# PHP can't read POST values inside IIS asp.net application

Tags: php, post, iis

A certain PHP page I have cannot read POSTed values. I have already read (and tried) suggestions from the following stack posts:

[PHP Can't get post data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42280476/php-cant-get-post-data)

[Can't get $_POST values (php, html)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380973/cant-get-post-values-php-html)

[Can't get the $_POST Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13608845/cant-get-the-post-variable)

[PHP $_POST not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002424/php-post-not-working)

[PHP POST not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914979/php-post-not-working)

[I can't read my POST HTTP request's body with PHP !](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362145/i-cant-read-my-post-http-requests-body-with-php)

I can prove that the posted values are coming from the sending PHP page. From the Network tab of Chrome dev tools:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
$firstName = trim($_POST["txtFirstName"]);
$lastName = trim($_POST["txtLastName"]);
$email = trim($_POST["txtEmail"]);
$phone = trim($_POST["txtPhone"]);

var_dump( $_POST );
echo "<br>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "<br>";
print_r($_REQUEST);
echo "<br>";
echo("firstName: $firstName" . "<br>");
echo("lastName: $lastName" . "<br>");
echo("txtFirstName: " . $_POST["txtFirstName"] . "<br>");
echo("txtLastName: " . $_POST["txtLastName"] . "<br>");
die();
```

And the results sent to the browser:

```
array(0) { } 
Array ( ) 
Array ( ) 
firstName: 
lastName: 
txtFirstName: 
txtLastName:
```

Here's a portion of the form from the submitting page:

```
<form method='post' action="Signup1.php" onsubmit="return checkForm(this)">
   ...
   <input name='txtFirstName' id='txtFirstName' maxlength="25" type='text' />
   ...
</form>
```

As you can see, everything is blank/empty. I have worked with PHP form posts many times over the years and never had a problem like this. I'm running PHP 5.6.11 locally on my IIS machine.

My php scripts are in the same folder tree shared by an asp.net app (in a configured IIS application). When I move my php scripts out of that tree, everything works fine. Why should that matter, and what is causing the problem?

Any ideas?

Comment: What do [`php://input`](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) and [`$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php) indicate?

Comment: Check your 2 maybes.

Comment: Can you try installing XAMPP? That would at least tell you if it's an IIS problem.

Comment: I discovered that my php scripts are in the same folder tree shared by an asp.net app. When I move my php scripts out of that tree, everything works fine. WTH??

Comment: HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is empty. "Check your 2 maybes" makes no sense to me. XAMPP - no thanks, IIS works fine with php, except in this odd case, been using it for years with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a problem with **url redirecting**. Sometimes it might happen that server is redirecting `your/route` to `your/route/` with trailing slash which causes emptying of $_POST, because of redirect.

Comment: Jozef, I verified there is no redirect going on other than the original form post from sender page to receiver page. And the fact that this all works *outside* the asp.net application virdir suggests something else is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and solved it by changing this:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

to this:

```
<modules>
```

in the "web.config".